# Unexpected Token error in my JSON when I try to read it in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I Have this JSON file that I have validated

[image]

```
[
{
    "CodigoProyecto": "ABREA242"
},
{
    "CodigoProyecto": "ABSUMTOT"
},
{
    "CodigoProyecto":  "AETXA521"
},
{
    "CodigoProyecto":  "ALGOH035"
},
{
    "CodigoProyecto":  "AMEZA582"
},
{
    "CodigoProyecto":  "ANACA001"
},
```

...
}
]

In my component, I have this

```
import proyectosEnSharePoint from './carpetasSharePoint.json';
proyectosEnSharePoint: { codigoProyecto: string }[] = proyectosEnSharePoint;
```

But when I run I get this error

Module parse failed: Unexpected token "�" (0xFFFD) in JSON at position 0 while parsing near "��[\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000{\u0000\r\u0000..."

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: The data `"��[\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000{\u0000\r\u0000..."` isn't valid JSON. Where does it come from? Maybe a wrong file encoding?

Comment: I don't see that characters in my JSON file

Comment: does your backend return application/json?

Comment: `\r` is an Apple line break. `\n` is a Linux line break. I've never seen these two mixed in the same file.

Comment: Ok I had UTF-16 instead UTF-8. Now solved thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I Had UTF-16 now solved changing it to UTF-8